# How to link docker host to container by name

Tags: docker

I know how to link two containers, but can I link the host to a container in a similar way?

I have an nginx server on the host, I want it to connect to a container named my-varnish, which is linked to my-apachephp linked to my-mysql.

Currently I either map a port -p 8080:80 or find the bridge IP address (which is different each time I destroy and build a new set of containers).  I would like to use the bridge IP by hostname without adding a dyn-dns registration process to each container.

Thoughts?!

Comment: What about user-defined network in docker?
You can create network and assign static ip addresses to your containers. And your nginx can connect to these containers using /etc/hosts.

Comment: maybe,  makes it less portable

Answer (score 0):

Use the Docker `run`'s add host functionality.It adds the host mapping in the container's host file.

From Usage :

```
--add-host value  Add a custom host-to-IP mapping (host:ip) (default [])
```